# Geodatabase network dataset error "cannot acquire a lock"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, network-analyst, network-dataset

I am trying to create a new network dataset within a feature dataset in a file geodatabase and keep getting the error "could not create network dataset. Cannot acquire a lock. Cannot acquire a lock." Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: That's because something else is accessing the database... close ALL Esri software, open one (and only one) ArcCatalog and try again. That should release the locks. If your database is in a network location it gets more complicated, in a file GDB you can tell the locks by looking into the database with explorer (or analogue) by looking for a sr.lock file, this will tell you what process (by PID) and computer it's being locked.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=cannot+acquire+lock

Comment: I tried copying the geodatabse onto a memory stick and creating the network dataset within this - this solved the problem.